# How to dynamically add a new line to a multiline textview

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have a multiline textview need to show the status of the server. So it should always add a new line when server status changes. However, the new line doesn't show up immediatelly but all show up at the end. I have set the `android:singleLine="false"`. I use following code to refresh the textview, but it still doesn't work.

```
private void SetLogTextView (string msg)
{   
  RunOnUiThread (() => logTextView.Text=logTextView.Text+msg );
}
```

I have contained "\n" in msg already. I just have msg1, msg2, and msg3, I want to them to show up in sequence. For instance, first msg1 show, then do something, then msg2 show, then do something, then msg3 show. Between each there should be a time interval. However, they didn't show at the right time, but all pop up at the end. This is what I want to fix. THX!

Comment: Sorry for not make my problem clear, I have updated it.

Comment: Then you should post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in below way -

```
private void SetLogTextView (string msg){   
    MyTextView.setText(MyTextView.getText().toString()+"\n"+msg);
}
```

It will add message in your text view in a new line.

Hope it will help you.

Alternatively you can use StringBuilder class.